# Regular expression for multiple emails with ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, email

I am attempting to use ng-pattern to filter out most major email addresses.

This is my regular expression, which admittedly I am not very versed in.

```
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model='email.userInput' 
placeholder="Please enter your work email" 
ng-pattern="/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(yahoo\.com|gmail\.com|msn\.com|hotmail\.com|live\.com)/">
```

I simply want to fail on the emails listed above... just looking for a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your alternating group of invalid email domains to a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`):

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?!yahoo\.com|gmail\.com|msn\.com|hotmail\.com|live\.com)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/cB1cY3)

---

To elaborate, a lookaround is a zero-width assertion meaning it doesn't actually match any characters.  Since this is a negative lookahead, as soon as we match the `@`, we will check to make sure it is not followed by `yahoo.com`, etc.  Because of how this works, we can actually simplify a lot of this (since `[A-Z0-9._%+-]+` may not cover a wide range of emails, which `type="email" should validate for us).  I would personally use [something like this](http://regex101.com/r/xE8mW3):

```
@(?!(?:yahoo|gmail|msn|hotmail|live)\.com|$)
```

This will only match the `@` symbol as long as they are not followed by yahoo/gmail/etc, `.com` and the end of the string.